# Triggering Twilio Rest API with node.

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

How do we trigger the Twilio REST API shown below, with nodeJS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To [use the REST API trigger for Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#rest-api) you need to make a POST request to the REST AOU URL for your flow, which will look a bit like this: `https://studio.twilio.com/v1/Flows/{{ FLOW_SID }}/Engagements`.

It is protected with basic auth, so you need to include your account sid and auth token as auth parameters. You should also set a `To` and `From` number. `To` should be the number you intend to interact with and `From` is your Twilio number.

In Node.js, using request, this would look like:

```
request = require('request');
request.post(flowUrl, {
  form: {
    To: toNumber,
    From: yourTwilioNumber
  },
  auth: {
    username: yourAccountSid,
    password: yourAuthToken
  }
});
```